# How to Show specific interface Statistics with netstat

Tags: networking, monitoring, freebsd, netstat

I want to show statistics of each interface .   netstat -w1  shows good result and netstat -i shows interface names . But I can not combine this 2 options .
for example  netstat -i ix1 -w1 dos not show only the ix1 interface statistics

What should I do ? 
Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

whit -I option problem solved not -i . pay attention to Capital [I] \
example : netstat -I ix1   -w1

Comment: This must be particular to macOS / BSDs, because Linux doesn't have either -I or -w.